# How to properly add default entries to database in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Mostly my entries in seeds.rb are simple, like this:

```
User.create!(
name: "Peter"
admin: false;
# etc.
)
```

If I get the "Can't mass-assign protected attributes" error, I make a small change in the model, in this case user.rb:

```
attr_accessible: name, admin
```

So far so good. But how am I supposed to seed entries into tables generated by a rails gem which adds another engine to my app? [Forem](https://github.com/radar/forem), for example. And I'm sure there are others.

I have added these entries to my seeds.rb file:

```
Forem::Category.create!(
name: "cat1"
)

Forem::Forum.create!(
title: "forum1",
description: "forum1 description",
category_id: 1
)

Forem::Topic.create!(
forum_id: 1,
user_id: 1,
subject: 'topic1',
locked: false,
pinned: false,
hidden: false,
)
```

Category and Forum are generated, Topic is not:

```
Can't mass-assign protected attributes: forum_id, user_id, locked, pinned, hidden
```

If I had a topic.rb model, I would know what to do. **But I don't have it**. Forem is an [engine](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/Rails/Engine.html) and I don't know of a way to make some attributes of model topic.rb visible.

I know that this line in application.rb:

```
config.active_record.whitelist_attributes = true
```

enables the protection against mass assignment. Disabling it leaves a huge security hole, so it's not an option. And disabling it didn't allow me to seed into topics table anyway.

I've also tried to use fixtures. I added this to my seeds.rb file:

```
require 'active_record/fixtures'
Fixtures.create_fixtures("#{Rails.root}/test/fixtures", "topics.yml")
```

test/topics.yml:

```
one:
  id: 1
  forum_id: 1
  user_id: 1
  subject: "topic1"
  created_at: 2012-05-19 19:54:19
  updated_at: 2012-05-19 19:54:20
  locked: false
  pinned: false
  hidden: false
  last_post_at: 2012-05-19 19:54:21
  state: "open"
  views_count: 3
```

Error I get is - **uninitialized constant Fixtures**

What's wrong with my seeds.rb and fixture? Or should I use a migration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Disabling it leaves a huge security hole, so it's not an option`

Nope, it's not a huge security hole. This is a controversial debate, but `attr_accessible` (and variants) are (in my and a lot of others opinion) not a good solution to the problem that is preventing users to create/update objects/attributes they should not. Put another way, `attr_accessible` is a model solution to a controller issue. Because that is the job of the controller to make sure that the data is cleaned and usable, to check wether the current user is allowed to do such things, etc.

So what I'd do would be to remove all references to `attr_accessible` and set `whitelist_attributes` to false.

Then it's up to you to filter your params in your controllers. You could do as done in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/1975644) or use [rails/strong_parameters](https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters), or any other way that might please you.

After that you would no longer have these issues while seeding

Comment: I see your point. But setting whitelist_attributes to false and restarting the server did not fix the issue. I think the reason lies within Forem gem.

Comment: you need to remove the `attr_accessible` & `attr_protected` instructions too

Answer (score 1):

Seeds.rb is just ruby code. You don't have to create the whole resource in one line.  Try something like this

```
topic = Forem::Topic.create(
  :subject => "topic 1",
  :locked => false
  # etc
)

topic.user_id = 1
topic.save
```